# Physical vs Virtual machine (HyperV R2) for Threat Management Gateway 2010 (TMG 2010)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-forefront-2010

What are the GOOD and BAD sides of using physical machine and what are the GOOD and BAD sides of using virtual machine (Hyper-V R2) for hosting TMG 2010 in NLB (aka 2 x TMG 2010)?

We're planning deployment of TMG in our network and we are discussing pro's and cons of one over the other. Possibly by using physical machine network latency would be lower then using virtual one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualizing adds overhead to just about every aspect of the machine. You'll find almost all of the cons boil down to that additional complexity.

The main Pros are that you can put those two (or more) TMGs on a cluster where you have can considerably better uptime, VMs are quicker to spin up, and dynamically allocating resources to them is considerably quicker and easier. These features are common to almost all virtualization deployments.

As with most virtualization deployments, if you're dedicating the whole machine to a VM, there's no point in adding the virtualization complexity. If however, you already have a VH Cluster and do not need to dedicate large amounts of hardware, it makes sense to use the cluster.

In the case of TMG, it's very network intensive, and lightly CPU & HD intensive. It's a good fit for virtualizing (we run it virtualized and have had no problems, though it's not heavily used).

Comment: We have right now 2 machines with 5 NIC's each on which couple of other VM machines are running. Is it true that if you dedicate a NIC to a Virtual machine the HOST is unlikely to have a problem with security ? I'm asking this since TMG complains when being on VM that the HOST isn't protected by it, but since the NIC is set to be only visible in Virtual Machine the security is good as the physical machine?

Comment: Correct, if the host doesn't have any bindings to the NIC then it's not connected. The Hypervisor actually controls the hardware, not the host OS.

Answer (score 1):

if you need raw power, process cpu/memory/network at max use physical
if you need to have multiple machines that are load balanced, get provisioned automatically as your load increases use vms.

a note on the 'private clouds' is:

let's say you need X amount of resources to process your application will call it XpowApp - this includes cpu,memory, disk, network etc.

now you have a bunch of vms that can process this amount of XpowApp at 75% from their total resources and at some point you have an increase of 50% from actual XpowApp then you go over 100% from what the vms can do ... so basically the vms become useless UNLESS you can bring a new physical server and set vms on it.  The same thing can happen on physical servers but they will be able to perform more then all the vms together because there is no virtualization layer to process.

ubuntu offers a very interesting alternative to this where you have your private cloud doing XpowApp and if you go over the capacity you can extend it over a public cloud and then you can support bursts with buying all the extra hardware.

Comment: I think you're a bit off topic. I'm not asking about VM vs Physical in general but in this specific case which is TMG. It's a special product with it's pro's and cons and that's why I ask about this since it's mostly network related and I wouldn't like to have huge network latency problems since all traffic between servers and users will be going thru TMG and all traffic to internet will go thru TMG as well.